# How to assume symbols are real & FullSimplify and Simplify working slow

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am calculating EigenSystem of symbolic 4X4 matrix and it fails to find eigen-vectors, althoug it succeed to find it for very similar matrix. I think that definig all symbols are real and positive can help. 
Is there a way to asuume this at the begining for all the calculations in the notebook?

Another problem is when trying to simplify expression by

`Simplify[ToRadicals@ComplexExpand[Re[diag0[[1]]], _Symbol \[Element] Reals]]`

it is running for a long time and then I get a massage that the kernal is not responding (What is the kernal?), so I choose Abort.
Is there another way to simplify the expressione?

Comment: What is `diag0[[1]]`?

Comment: diag0[[1]] is sopme complex expression I got from earlier calculation. Is it matter how it looks?